# Regex to get a specificpart of a text

Tags: regex

I've got a text and I need to get the floor digit or text. The text can be formatted in 2 ways:

(roadname) (roadnumber), (floor). (side)

```
Roadname 36, 4. tv.
```

or

```
Roadname 36, st. tv.
```

The difference is the floor can either be ground level or a number.

I'm using Xpath to crawl website adresses, and need a Regex pattern to only get the floor digit/text.

**EDIT

```
\S*(?=\.)
```

seems to do it

Comment: Where is your regex failing?

Comment: Note that if you split your strings with space, the answer is always the third result.

Comment: I was also going to say, no real need for a RegEx.

Comment: You could also get the index of ", " and ". " then whatever the difference is is your floor digits/text. This is assuming you've already split/formatted your addresses into an array of some kind which it seems you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is using this pattern:

```
/,\s*(\S*)/
```

... that'll capture any sequence of non-whitespace symbols that follow the comma.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oD1vQ3).

Another approach (if that's the only text to be processed) is capturing the first sequence of symbols preceding the dot:

```
/\S*(?=\.)/
```

In this case using capturing groups is not required, but the regex flavor should support lookaheads AND `roadname` should never contain dots.

Finally, you can just split your string by whitespace and take the third element of resulting array - but that'll fail if roadname has whitespace in it.